# Data Reconcilition with Python, outof memory error

Tags: python, database, bigdata, reconciliation

I want to reconcile by reading data from two different databases. I get an out of memory error while reading the data for a job that will run on a single machine.

I read the data with pandas by taking two different SQL as source and target. I can't try chunksize because I need to pull the same data to reconcile from two different systems.

My main problem is to be able to pull the same data from two different systems in chunks and compare them in a loop.

available code:

```py
smartdq_logging('Log', gv_log_level, f"connecting to source db...")
cl_connect_sourcedb = lib.environment_connection.DBConnect()
cl_connect_sourcedb.connect_with_environment_id(environmentIdSource, "SMARTDQ", cl_connect_smartdq) 

smartdq_logging('Log', gv_log_level, f"connecting to target db...")
cl_connect_target = lib.environment_connection.DBConnect()
cl_connect_target.connect_with_environment_id(environmentIdTarget, "SMARTDQ", cl_connect_smartdq) 


source_query = """SELECT
    LEVEL AS id,
    ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 99999) / 100000, 5) AS value
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= 1000000"""

target_query = """SELECT
    LEVEL AS id,
    ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 99999) / 100000, 5) AS value
FROM
    DUAL
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= 1000000"""


print('start recon...')
df_source = db_func.read_data_to_dataframe(source_query, cl_connect_sourcedb, "original")

df_target = db_func.read_data_to_dataframe(source_query, cl_connect_target, "original")
```

Comment: Could you sort the data in your sql statement, maybe that allows you the read from the databases in chunks. Or could you replicate the data in a single database?

Comment: both queries can result in close to 50 million data, so sorting can be very costly. However, I would still like to hear if you have any suggestions. @IzaakCornelis